# Change the default color of formula embedded in text

Tags: stylesheet, slideshows

We can use `Ctrl+(` to start a new math cell in a text cell. But is there anyway to make the default color of the formula different?

I am making a presentation with Mathematica so I want the formula to standout everywhere.

As you can see, it's bit difficult to see where is the formula.

[image]